# Change UINavigationBar's color

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationbar

I'm using Objective-C. Here I need to change the background color of an UINavigationBar. And I tried this code below:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
```

But the result is:

[image]

What I want is change the color of the NavigationBar into the green color below instead of a blurry green as it is now. Someone please help me.

Answer (score 2):

do like select your `Naigation Bar` on storyboard and change the property of bar tint in directly in inspector

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just add this code

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use appearance

```
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
```

Hope this help